# Return stream from array as int[] instead of Integer[]

Tags: java, arrays, integer, java-stream

I have this array:

```
Integer[] originalItems = itemsArray.stream()
            .distinct()
            .sorted()
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

I would like to return it as `int[]` rather than as `Integer[]`.

I have tried to call `.toArray(int[]::new)` but I get this error:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) A exist so that int[] conforms to A[]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

instead of

```
.toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

because

```
<A> A[] toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator);
```

doesn't work with primitive types.